# Flickr api returns data fail() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flickr

I checked the Flickr Api url and it returns data correctly for my images, but when i include in `$.ajax()` and `$.getJson()` it does not load data neither executes the functions like `success: function()` in case of `$.ajax()`.

**Code:**

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&user_id=xxxxxxxxx&format=json&per_page=500", function() {
console.log( "success" ); //Does not Show
})
.done(function() {
console.log( "second success" ); //Does not Show
})
.fail(function(data) {
console.log( data ); // Shows correct JSON data here in ResponseText of data object.
})
.always(function() {
console.log( "complete" );
});
```

Why does it show in `fail()`. Am i doing things right?

Comment: Did you check the status code of your response in Network tab ?

Comment: @Arkantos `status: 200,statuscode: .ajax/v.statusCode()`

Comment: @Arkantos i am using `jquery-2.1.1.min.js`. Does that create a problem in my case?

Comment: try adding `jsoncallback=?` to the flickr URL

Comment: @LShetty.. we're not sure if Flickr API supports JSONP :)

Comment: @Arkantos it does. Take a look here [http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=jQuery1102008065663510933518_1425743333483&tags=mount+rainier&tagmode=any&format=json&_=1425743333484](http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=jQuery1102008065663510933518_1425743333483&tags=mount+rainier&tagmode=any&format=json&_=1425743333484)

Comment: @harikrishnan.n0077 look at [an example here that fetches Flickr data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Answer (score 2):

By default the [flickr API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html) returns JSON wrapped in a callback function name (by default `jsonFlickrApi`). So the JSON string `'{"foo": "bar"}'` would be returned as `'jsonFlickrApi('{"foo": "bar"})'`.

This is part of the [JSONP specification](http://json-p.org/) to allow requesting JSON via a `<script src="...">` tag.

Since you don't want to use a script tag to load the data, the flickr API allows switching off that wrapping, returning the raw JSON instead. To do this, pass `nojsoncallback=1` as part of the URL.

I would generally recommend passing the URL parameters as a JS object, so jQuery can URL-encode them correctly. Also that's much nicer to look and a lot easier to modify than a long URL string.

The following is working nicely (deconstructed for reusability):

```
var flickrApiSetup = {
    api_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    format: "json",
    per_page: 500,
    nojsoncallback: 1
};

function callFlickrApi(methodName, params) {
    params = $.extend({method: methodName}, flickrApiSetup, params);
    return $.getJSON("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/", params)
        .fail(function (jqXhr, status, errorThrown) {
            console.log(methodName + " failed", status, errorThrown, jqXhr);
        });
}

function getPublicPhotos(userNsid, params) {
    params = $.extend({user_id: userNsid}, params);
    return callFlickrApi("flickr.people.getPublicPhotos", params);
}

getPublicPhotos("47768716@N02", {per_page: 10, page: 2}).done(function (data) {
    console.log( data );
});
```

Comment: Your answer talks about JSONP but do you've any working CORS example with Flickr :) ?

Comment: Hm. My code runs, returning data from the flickr API. What more can you ask?

Comment: Yes you're correct. I can see CORS headers for your URL `/services/rest` but not for the URL that I tried in my example :)